# Equivalent of jQuery.animate step function when using CSS3 transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm using CSS transitioning to animate circles (nodes) around the screen.

CSS:

```
.circle {-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out; }
```

JS:

```
 $('.circle').css({ webkitTransform: "translate3d(20px, 20px, 0px)" })
```

I'd like to be able to know the translation properties at all times, so I can update lines connecting the nodes.

If I was using jQuery animation, I could use the "step" function. Is there any similar thing in CSS transitions? I've seen a "webkitTransitionEnd" event, but nothing for individual animation steps.

Or will I have to do it with timers?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could use a timer and get the computed values of the animated element, but its almost guaranteed to run slow. I never felt the need to access computed values in steps and just started 2 or more animations simultaneously.

If you want to animate more complex stuff like circles with lines between them, you should consider using a canvas library like [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

There already are some similar demos like what you're trying to accomplish, like [this](http://raphaeljs.com/gear.html) one.